# Custom post.php

Tags: custom-content

Is there any way to define a post.php for a Custom Content Type?

I am trying to remove the Permalink, the Slug and the Preview Changes Button from the edit/creation page of an item in my custom content type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove Preview Button

```
function posttype_admin_css() {
    global $post_type;
    $post_types = array(
                        /* set post types */
                        'post_type_name'
                  );
    if(in_array($post_type, $post_types))
    echo '<style type="text/css">#post-preview, #view-post-btn{display: none;}</style>';
}
add_action( 'admin_head-post-new.php', 'posttype_admin_css' );
add_action( 'admin_head-post.php', 'posttype_admin_css' );
```

To remove slug

```
function vipx_remove_cpt_slug( $post_link, $post, $leavename ) {

    if ( 'post_type_name' != $post->post_type || 'publish' != $post->post_status ) {
        return $post_link;
    }

    $post_link = str_replace( '/' . $post->post_type . '/', '/', $post_link );

    return $post_link;
}
add_filter( 'post_type_link', 'vipx_remove_cpt_slug', 10, 3 );
```

Source:
http://vip.wordpress.com/documentation/remove-the-slug-from-your-custom-post-type-permalinks/
http://wpsnipp.com/index.php/functions-php/hide-post-view-and-post-preview-admin-buttons/

---

If I understood your question correctly, here is your answer.

```
single-typename.php
archive-typename.php
```

For example, you've a custom post type defined as book. single-book.php should be you're looking for.

Comment: The question seems to be about admin editor rather than front end template.